# DJango eror: TypeError, Exception Value:__call__(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: python, django, backend

I was trying to develop facial based attendance system, where user enter name,email and image in the database . tO Recognize, user enter image which recognise face endpoints using Python's face recognition library (https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/). I defined database in models.py as

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    face_encodings = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
```

Similary, I have defened register and recognize function in views.py as

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #name = request.POST['name']
        #email = request.POST['email']
        #image_file = request.FILES['image']
        name = request.POST.get('name', '') # Use get method to get the value of 'name' key
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        image_file= request.FILES.get('image', None)
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_file)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
        user = User(name=name, email=email,face_encodings=face_encodings)
        user.save()
        
        messages.error(request, 'User registered')
      
        return render(request, 'register.html')
    
    return render(request, 'register.html')
    
    
def recognize(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_file = request.FILES.get('image', None)
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_file)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)
        
        recognized_users = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            users = User.objects.all()
            for user in users:
                user_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(user.face_encodings)[0]
                distance = face_recognition.face_distance([user_face_encoding], face_encoding)[0]
                if distance < 0.6:
                    recognized_users.append({'name': user.name, 'email': user.email})
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'recognized_users': recognized_users})
    
    return render(request, 'recognize.html')
```

I could register the user.But when I enter to recognize by uploading image . I got the error:

```
TypeError at /recognize/
__call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.fhog_object_detector, image: array, upsample_num_times: int=0) -> _dlib_pybind11.rectangles

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.fhog_object_detector object at 0x00000229365A5AF0>, '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', 1
```

What could be the solution for this error?

I tried changing the default value of face_encoding  in models.py.

Here is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"C:\Users\rabinG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File 
"C:\Users\rabinG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)
File 
  "C:\Users\rabinG\Desktop\python_intern\myproject\myapp\views.py", 
 line 43, in recognize
user_face_encoding = 
face_recognition.face_encodings(user.face_encodings)[0]
File 
 "C:\Users\rabinG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
 packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 213, in face_encodings
  raw_landmarks = _raw_face_landmarks(face_image, 
 known_face_locations, model)
File 
 "C:\Users\rabinG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 156, in _raw_face_landmarks
face_locations = _raw_face_locations(face_image)
File 
"C:\Users\rabinG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 105, in _raw_face_locations
return face_detector(img, number_of_times_to_upsample)

Exception Type: TypeError at /recognize/
 Exception Value: __call__(): incompatible function arguments. The 
 following argument types are supported:
1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.fhog_object_detector, image: array, 
upsample_num_times: int=0) -> _dlib_pybind11.rectangles

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.fhog_object_detector object at 
0x000001F1DB875C70>, '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', 1
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback from the console.

Comment: @KlausD. I have mentioned error trackback